# Rotate player on z axis while walking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm currently in progress of a new game where my character has to move. While my character walks forward and i'm rotating it on the z axis, it just rotates instead of walking down the new z axis.

```
void Update()
{      
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Condition", 1);
            moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            moveDir *= speed;
            moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
        {
            anim.SetInteger("Condition", 0);
            moveDir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        moveDir.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    rot += Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rot, 0);        
}
```

}

I want to be able to walk forward while changing the z axis instead of walking then stop and then walk again.

Comment: Likely because the move direction is overwriting your rotation

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using a CharacterController because your call to controller.move() overwrites the rotation ... you need to write a custom move function.